# Repository Enforced Global Ignore Pattern

Tags: svn

Besides making sure devs have a global ignore pattern in place with Tortoise is there a way to safeguard against this by enforcing it from the server itself via repository so that you don't have to worry about devs checking in wrong files?

Answer (score 2):

That is what [**pre-commit hooks**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) are for.